# Make an existing folder into a repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I've decided that modifying files directly in notepad is probably dangerous and it was about time to have some proper source control (I am quite new to source control). I have installed VisualSVN server on my server and TortoiseSVN on my client machine. I can create new folders fine, check them our etc. However, on my server, I have an existing folder structure in place for IIS and there are links based on this location everywhere. How can I make the entire folder work with SVN without moving the files?

Comment: Don't you want to backup those files as well? (The ones that are beyond the links)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a simple solution for checking in an existing directory structure:

1. Open the repository browser of TortoiseSVN (or any other SVN client you prefer) and create a new directory for the project you want to check-in.
2. Check-out this newly created empty directory from SVN somewhere
3. Open the checked-out directory and move the contained hidden `.svn` directory into the root directory of your project. This enables the context menus from TortoiseSVN for all files and sub-folders.
4. Add every file and folder you want to check-in (context menu command *Add...*)
5. Execute *SVN Commit...* on the project root folder

Comment: Note: Step 1 assumes that your repository structure is set up to have multiple projects in a single repository (i.e., [option one in the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s04.html)). If instead you put each project in separate repositories (i.e. option two), you won't be able to do that from your repository browser. You will need to create the new repository on the svn server itself.

Answer (score 17):

An even simpler way than [Robert's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7674380/971299) (although lifting from it):

1. Open the repository browser of TortoiseSVN and create a new directory for the project you want to check-in.
2. Check-out this newly created empty directory from SVN **as the directory you are wanting to add** (ignore the warning about checking out into a non-empty directory).
3. Execute 'SVN Commit...' on the directory you are wanting to commit, selecting the files you want to add from the commit window.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add a step between 3 and 4:

3.5. Ignore the automatically generated files (context menu command Add to ignore list...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what the others above have mentioned, however, if you wish to just use what you have instead of adding and committing, you can simply fool SVNServe.

For this example our existing repo is "TEST_REPO"

Go to your command line.

Create a new directory called "new". CD into it.

In our "new" directory run the following:

```
C:\new\mkdir TEST_REPO
C:\new\svnadmin create TEST_REPO
```

Now you will have a repo in the "TEST_REPO" directory.

Run:

```
C:\new\cd TEST_REPO
C:\new\TEST_REPO\del *.* /S /Q
```

(rd to remove directories if needed, sorry, not a windows person)

Now, move the files from your existing "TEST_REPO" into the "C:\new\TEST_REPO\" folder.  Then run:

```
C:\new\TEST_REPO\svnadmin verify .
```

You should see SVN verify all of the source in your repository.  Easy peasy.